# Why might Ironsides and the USS constitution be hostile with me?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm pretty late in the game so I guess I could have done something. As far as I can remember I have had no direct with this ship or crew. I read that this was a cool mission with a legendary gun reward. Is there a way to fix this so that they are no longer hostile?

I am playing on Xbox One.

Comment: Did you ever speak with the Lookout? See http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Voyage_of_the_U.S.S._Constitution for details.

Comment: Were you using Power Armor with the Targeting HUD Modification when you approached the ship?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the notes on the [quest's wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Voyage_of_the_U.S.S._Constitution), there are a few ways you can inadvertently fail this quest:

> 1. If your companion is wearing power armor that has Tesla Coils, it may trigger hostility in the robots, causing you to fail the mission.
> 2. If Preston Garvey accompanies the Sole Survivor the robots will become hostile. To avoid failing the quest, simply walk around them and they will only attack Preston.

Do either of these sound like they may have been the cause?